# Contact programs about wrong dates for part-time research assistantship in college?

Tags: graduate-admissions, ethics, cv

So I am submitting applications for this cycle (Fall 2021). I graduated from school a few years ago and did occasional part-time work as a research assistant in college. In my application, I recorded *September 2014* to September 2017 as a research assistant. Though I just realized, I was a research assistant from *January 2015* to September 2017. So I was one semester off. This was an honest mistake, and since this was 5 years ago and part-time, I was a little fuzzy on the dates to be honest.

Should I reach out to programs pre-emptively? I don't want them to think this was intentional.

EDIT: Fwiw, the application was submitted about a month ago.

EDIT2: I ended up writing a brief email like the one in the comments section. Will update on outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is unlikely to be a big deal for most purposes, it is best to be honest and clear. Send a note and update the CV.

Mistakes happen. We are human and are generally recognized as such. There might be a rare exception in which a correction is necessary, but not for most. Still, it is courteous, clean, and neat.

Comment: "Hello, in the interest of transparency, I realized that one of my undergraduate research experiences from several years ago started 1 semester later than what is in my CV. I updated a corrected CV. My sincerest apologies for the oversight." 

How would that sound?

Comment: Sounds about right, but you may not need to send the CV, just the note, with an offer to send the corrected version. But if you haven't gotten feedback in a month, it may be moot, I'm afraid.

Comment: Interview invitations did not go out yet (nor rejections) so I don't think I am already de facto rejected -- though it is somewhat of a reach school so I might be! Thank you for your confirmation. Do you think there would be any harm in sending the CV?

Comment: Can't say, actually. If you have a contact person, perhaps it would be fine, but things might get lost if it is office staff handling such things.

Comment: I see no harm in including the updated CV in the email. A small attachment isn't realistically a burden on anyone, and you skip an unnecessary email loop.

Comment: Alright, I just sent the email with updated CV. My intuition is that nobody will read and/or forward it, but at least (a) I will not feel guilty and (b) I can show I flagged the discrepancy if it comes up.

Comment: @Buffy At this time of year there is no reason to assume a 1 month delay means anything, at least in my field. Many positions won't even have closing dates until round about now, and the first responses usually come out in the new year. By the time the rejections come in the summer it's pretty obvious, although not necessarily correct if you're applying for fixed-term positions that could come up at shorter notice.

Comment: @JessicaB, true enough. I was overly pessimistic. But you should at least get an acknowledgement.